# APL Session over HTTP?

Tags: apl

Is there a way to have an APL session communicating using HTTP?  That is, instead of using the IDE which is already built into APL, to start APL somewhere and send requests such as `)load`, `)save`, `)copy`, `1+1`, `run`, etc. and have the reply text sent back.  Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an APL system today which gives you the option of starting up communicating over a port.  Perhaps something like `myapl -port=80 -protocol=http`.  But it does not exist.

Having said that, look at the functions SERVER.RECEIVE and SERVER.RUN (SERVER is the namespace) in the WWW workspace, which comes with Dyalog APL, at least in my older version.  You should be able to change these functions as needed to have a dialogue with APL as a simple server using HTTP.  Other APLs should offer similar capabilities.

Also, have a look at http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/satn39a.htm. A similar idea, but from 35 years ago.

Comment: Have python on linux working with APL on windows the using your suggestion the server workspace.  How is the best way to handle APL characters?

Comment: APL Chars: In this case, forget it, write cover functions instead.  
Rather than ¯1 2 3 4 5 ÷ 6 7 ¯8 9 10 
use (-1) 2 3 4 5 div 6 7 (-8) 9 10

Comment: See http://www.jsoftware.com/user/jserver.htm - this uses telnet typically on port 23

Answer (score 2):

in GNU APL you can run an APL script as CGI script.
See http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/APL_demo.html

/// Jürgen

Answer (score 1):

[Dyalog](http://www.dyalog.com/) are working on the RIDE, see also http://www.dyalog.com/dyalog/development-environment.htm
During #Dyalog14 they demonstrated running APL on a Raspberry Pi and debugging from windows as well as running APL on a remote machine somewhere in the web and connecting with the local IDE - very impressive stuff! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Dyalog APL is toying with it's use within a Jupyter Notebook -- that would probably meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

APLcloud.com  has some tools to integrate APL with HTML.  The trick is to use a Web Service on a server and then use browser or client APL UI to make the HTTP connection.

Dyalog APL has a free open source web server written in APL  (MiServer or mserver.dws).

A small test web site has been experimenting in automatic porting of an APL program so it instantly runs on a web page. The APL programmer does not need to know or use any HTML or Web code.  100%  APL to Web using simple javascript to call Web Service on MiServer with Dyalog APL.   http://APLAPPS.com